# Solving a linear PDE with conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve this PDE subject to the initial and boundary condition. Is there a straightforward way to do so?

[image]

Comment: This is the transport equation, it can be solved with characteristics.

Comment: Just so you know, the comment above is referring to the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).